# bar not displayed in Highcharts for Higher values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a stacked column chart using highcharts. In that if one bar has higher values then the other bar is not displayed.

Below is the sample series

```
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5000, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2000, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
```

I have done it here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kasinaat007/Layg0s3f/1/).

I have tried using y-axis type as logarithmic since my chart will definitely have zero values it throws Highcharts error #10.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
    plotOptions: {
       series: {
           minPointLength: 20
        }
     }
```

to increase the minimum plot length of the column. Please modify `20` with appropriate value.
I have updated your code here. please check https://jsfiddle.net/6paovjd5/

Setting up the `minPointLength` does not work correctly with stacked bar charts
because of the issue reported : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1776

To overcome the bug reported you can replace the `plotOptions` with the following code

```
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent',
         minPointLength: 40,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        }
    }
},
```

Please check the Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ryu59n4p/

Comment: even in this method in a single bar if any one value is high the other one is not displayed.Check in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ryu59n4p/

Comment: Hi Kasinaat 007, your example seems to work properly. Could you describe more precisely what effect you want to achieve?